# Automating ldapsearch with bash using variables

Tags: bash, virtualbox, centos7, openldap

I perform an ldapsearch like

```
ldapsearch -D "cn=ldapadm,dc=test,dc=com" -w ldappasswd -b "dc=test,dc=com" objectclass=*
```

and it works fine.

Now I want to substitute the input with varaibles:

```
BASEDN="cn=ldapadm,dc=test,dc=com"
PASSWD="ldappasswd"
BINDDN="dc=test,dc=com"

ldapsearch -D "${BASEDN}" -w "${PASSWD}" -b "${BINDDN}" objectclass=*
```

But I get an

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

error...
The problematic part here is the PASSWD substitution. The other two substitutions are working fine.

I am using CentOS7 on VirtualBox.
The password does not contain special characters.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It should work, from what you've shown. Does `ldappasswd` contain `$` or `"` or other magic characters?

Comment: Not sure it will solve your problem but you should quote your asterisk, i.e. `"objectclass=*"` instead of `objectclass=*`.

Comment: You can see what is passed exactly by setting the xtrace option: `set -x; ldap -D "${BASEDN}" -w "${PASSWD}" -b "${BINDDN}" objectclass=*` which will output to stderr the command line after variable expansion. Please run the command that works (without variables) and the command that does not work and look if there’s a difference. Hopefully you will see that a special character is different, or maybe a whitespace at the beginning or the end of a variable. PS. you can disable the xtrace option by calling `set +x`

Comment: Also, it is a bad practice to pass a password as command-line argument because every logged-in user can parse arguments of running processes, including processes of other users. You may use the `-y passwdfile` option instead, with a file which is readable exclusively to the user who is intended to run the ldapsearch command. Incidentally it may solve your issue as well.

Comment: Thanks vdavid. That did the trick. Would you like to post your own answer, so that I can give credits to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set -x; ldapsearch -D "${BASEDN}" -w "${PASSWD}" -b "${BINDDN}" objectclass=*
```

revealed the problem. I loaded the values from a file and there was an invisible linebreak at the end of each string.

Output:

```
ldapsearch -D cn=ldapadm,dc=test,dc=com\r -w ldappasswd\r -b dc=test,dc=com\r objectclass=*
```

I removed \r calling

```
PASSWD=`echo "${value_from_file}"| sed 's/\\r//g'`
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use
echo -n "password-here" > password_file

Or, set as environment variable

read -s “password”
read -s -p "password:" password
password: enter password here
echo -n $password | ldapsearch -LLL -D cn=whatever,o=whateverelse -y /dev/stdin